# Преобразование строки в дату

Tags: java

Есть переменная типа стринг `s="05.09.2013";` пытаюсь преобразовать в тип `Date`. Не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
format.applyPattern("dd.mm.yyyy");
Date docDate= format.parse(docDate);
```

Comment: Как указал @GlyyK буквы m не того размера. (m - минуты)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

dd - День

MM - Месяц

yyyy - год

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Answer (score 7):

Вариант автора будет работать тоже, только немного изменить надо:

`String s="05.09.2013";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
format.applyPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date docDate= format.parse(s);`