# Как правильно из строки, которая записана в файл.txt, создать объект и закинуть его в список?

Tags: java, файлы, дата, io, parse

Начал изучать `java` и программирование в целом совсем недавно. Так, что не знаю элементарных вещей.

Вот строка в в файле worker.txt

```
1 Ivan Sidorov 12.03.1993 12.03.2019
```

Вот класс работника:

Представим, что в классе есть геттеры-сеттеры и конструкторы.

```
public class Worker {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private Date dateOfEmployment; //время устройства на работу
}
```

Вот другой класс с реализацией:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        starter();
    }

    public static void starter() {
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/worker.txt");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            System.out.println(parseFileToObjectList(scanner));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Файл не найден");
        }
    }

    public static List<Worker> parseFileToObjectList(Scanner scanner) {
        List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] worker = line.split(" ");

            Worker currentWorker = new Worker(Long.parseLong(worker[0]), worker[1], worker[2], (worker[3]), worker[4]);
            workers.add(currentWorker);
        }
        return workers;
    }
}
```

Я не могу понять как парсить дату рождения и дату устройства на работу из строки в нужный тип данных (как я запарсил `Long -> Long.parseLong(worker[0]`). И вообще правильно ли я делаю?

Comment: Вы точно искали в интернете [_как получить дату из строки java_](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8+java)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование строки в дату 2013](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/212536/); [Как преобразовать строку в дату, используя при этом несколько шаблонов дат? 2019](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960674/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала неплохо бы отказаться от класса Date. Начиная с java 8, появился пакет java.time, настоятельно рекомендуется использовать именно его. Кроме того, если уж вы говорите о преобразовании массива стрингов в объект, то лучше это делать не в методе, который парсит данные, а в конструкторе объекта. Посему ваш класс будет выглядеть так:

```
class Worker {
    
    private final static DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private LocalDate dateOfEmployment; //дата трудоустройства

    public Worker(String[] args) {
        this.id = Long.valueOf(args[0]);
        this.firstName = args[1];
        this.lastName = args[2];
        this.dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(args[3], FORMATTER);
        this.dateOfEmployment = LocalDate.parse(args[4], FORMATTER);
    }
    
}
```

В этом случае вашему парсеру больше не нужно знать ничего о полях класса, объекты которого он создает, ведь ваш класс принимает просто массив строк и сам знает как корректно преобразовать их в объект. Посему парсер можно сделать более универсальным:

```
public class App {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Worker> result = parseFileToObjectList("src/main/resources/worker.txt", " ", Worker.class);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    
    private static <T> List<T> parseFileToObjectList(String fileName, String separator, Class<T> modelClass) throws Exception {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
            List<T> cities = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] splitLine = scanner.nextLine().split(separator);
                Constructor<T> constructor = modelClass.getConstructor(String[].class);
                cities.add(constructor.newInstance(new Object[] {splitLine}));
            }
            return cities;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Теперь с помощью этого кода вы можете парсить данные из текстового файла с любыми разделителями в любой кастомный класс, сождержащий конструктор, который принимает массив строк.

Если есть вопросы, не стесняйтесь их задавать

Comment: Блин, я даже о таком и подумать не мог. Очень грамотный вариант. И за подсказку с LocalDate спс.